# Why are half my Christmas lights not turning on?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have a set of Christmas lights for which the second half doesn't light up. My understanding is that the individual branches are in parallel whereas the lights in each branch is in series.

[image]
[image]

The plug at the end of the set works fine, so current seems to travel to the end of the wires correctly.

What could be causing this?

Comment: A string of 100 is really 2 strings of 50 and yes they are in series.  One "string" has a break in it.  Might be caused by a loose or damaged bulbs.  Bulbs have a shunt device so that if the filament burns out, one bulb won't kill the string, but a loose or damaged bulb is another story--that will break the series circuit.

Comment: The plugs always work and are parallel to either branch. One of the bulbs on the second half is not making a good connection. you can use a volt meter between the plug and the socket to help determine which one.

Comment: As the next question will be what to do.. Throw it away. Trying to repair these things is seriously not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Tyson The first half definitely doesn't need the second half to function, we actually cut the two wires just before the first dark bulb and nothing changed. Whether the second half would work after removing a bulb from the first is unclear to me.

Comment: @agentp After a long and thorough investigation, this is our conclusion as well.

Comment: Yes @isanae the two halves are independent.  If you notice, there are 3 wires between all bulbs EXCEPT between the 2 bulbs where you just cut.  There are only 2 wires between the 2 bulbs that seperate the half-strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Christmas lights, they are wired with a backbone of 2 wires carrying power through to the socket on the other end.

Then, they have one or more strings of 40-50.  Each string taps one backbone wire at one end, and the other backbone wire at the other end.

Within each string, all lamps are in series.  A failure will darken the whole string, except the bulbs have fusible shunts so if a bulb burns out, it will shunt and the other bulbs will remain lit (at a slightly higher voltage, burning them out faster).

When you have a segment with 40-50 out, that means a shunt has failed, or you have a loose socket or broken wire.

They make toners specifically for Christmas tree lights (a cheapie version of a Fluke toner, I presume) that will help you find the bad one.

Comment: I was mostly confused by the fact that half of it worked fine and that the plug also worked. I now understand both halves and the plug are independent, which is nice, but I'm not sure I understand the rationale (who wants half a set?). In any case, that set is now part of my collection of spare bulbs.

Comment: The rationale is that they are 2.5 volt lamps in series.  Because in series 2.5*50=125 which is line voltage.

Comment: @Tyson That is a surprisingly good rationale.